# How do I use Kotlin object by reflection

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Let's say I need to set property A given by a String in Kotlin object O given by a String by reflection. If O was a class I could do something like this (disregard it has no sense):

```
fun setValue(ownerClassName: String, fieldName: String, value : Any) {
    val enclosingClass = Class.forName(ownerClassName).newInstance()
    val enclosingClassField = enclosingClass.javaClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
    enclosingClassField.isAccessible = true
    enclosingClassField.set(enclosingClass, value)
}
```

But how would I do it if O is an object?

Comment: `o.javaClass`?.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to do this when you're passing in an existing object instance (say `o: Any`) rather than `ownerClassName: String`?

Comment: Is this Downwoting Week or something on StackOverflow?

Comment: Every week is downvoting week on SO ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`KClass` has an [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html) field:

```
Class.forName(ownerClassName).kotlin.objectInstance
```

This is built into Kotlin reflection.

> **Returns**: The instance of the object declaration, or null if this class is not an object declaration.

This would be even nicer if `KClass` had a `forName` method, but sadly it [does not](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10440) (yet), so we need to instead get the (Java) `Class` and convert it to `KClass`.

You can get a `KClass` instance from a `Class` by using the `.kotlin` extension property.

Then you can continue with the rest of your code. I converted this to Kotlin's reflection library:

```
val kClass = Class.forName(ownerClassName).kotlin
// Get the object OR a new instance if it doesn't exist
val instance = kClass.objectInstance ?: kClass.java.newInstance()

val member = kClass.memberProperties
// Has to be a mutable property, otherwise we can't set it
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
// Check the name
        .filter { it.name == fieldName }
        .firstOrNull()

// Set the property
member?.setter?.call(instance, value)
```

Here is a working test:

```
object TestObject {
    var field = 3
}

fun setValue(ownerClassName: String, fieldName: String, value: Any) {
    val kClass = Class.forName(ownerClassName).kotlin
    val instance = kClass.objectInstance ?: kClass.java.newInstance()

    val member = kClass.memberProperties.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
            .firstOrNull { it.name == fieldName }

    member?.setter?.call(instance, value)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(TestObject.field) // 3
    setValue("some.package.TestObject", "field", 4)
    println(TestObject.field) // 4
}
```

Comment: What do you do once you have this?

Comment: It seems OP is wondering what the alternative to `newInstance` would be for an `object` (singleton), since you can't make a new instance. At least that's how I interpreted it. Then you would continue setting the field by using the rest of the code in the question

Comment: Ok, I think I interpreted the question differently (hence the downvote which I now retracted) - I assumed the OP meant an arbitrary object, rather than a Kotlin singleton object.

Comment: Actualy the question was about Kotlin singleton created by "object" keyword as opposed to "class" keyword.

Comment: Well, Aleksiej was first and his answer seems straightforward. And it does what was required.

Comment: @ssuukk the first point may be true, though it is arguably a better idea/more idiomatic to use [`kotlin.reflect`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html).

Comment: Can you explain why do we need seemingly unused variable "instance" in your answer?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to use the reference while setting, that is fixed now

Comment: I agree, this is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 12):

`object` is translated into a class with a private constructor and a static  field called `INSTANCE` where the only instance is stored when this class is loaded, so replacing `Class.forName(ownerClassName).newInstance()` with

```
Class.forName(ownerClassName).getDeclaredField("INSTANCE").get(null)
```

should work.

---

Javadoc:

- [`Class#forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)
- [`Class#getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String))
- [`Field#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: What is `ownerClassName` now?

Comment: please provide an (at least) brief explanation how this code works. Thanks

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The name of the `object`.

Comment: @crgarridos Edited, but really looking at the Javadoc for the methods  `Class#getDeclaredField` and for `Field#get` would give the explanation.

Comment: This is failing in case of pro-guard enable. because object class(ownerClassName) is obfuscated.